# API design for api which returns true or false

Tags: api-design, rest

What should be the API design for an API which accepts a list of for example students ids and client want to know that if any one of this student doesn't contain surname.

I am just confused what should be an rest API design for such API, where client is just interested in true or false

Here true means all the student contain surname

Whereas false state not all student contain surname.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple `for` for this situation, something like this in python:

```
def check_user(users: list):
    result = True
    for u in users:
        if not u.has_surname():
            result = False
    data = {'result': result}
    return Response(data=data, status=200)
```